# List of Dropbox Created File Names

Tags: dropbox, file-sharing

I am looking for a list documenting the known file naming styles that are created by Dropbox.  Two that I know of are

```
 *(conflicted copy)*
 *(restored)*
```

which are created when there are multiple changes to a file.

Are there others?  Do they always have the "(" and ")" in the name?

I am writing a script to detect these and notify me so that I can review and take appropriate action.